# Number 5's power source - what is it?

Tags: short-circuit

In the film *Short Circuit*, we see the S.A.I.N.T robots getting charged and when a lightning bolt hits a power line it hits Number 5.  It would seem most likely that these robots were being charged from that point.  This seemed to be a serious amount of energy as it appeared to be directly connected to a power line and the connection point was a massive machine.

So with that established, my question is: following his escape from NOVA, where did Number 5 source his power from to recharge?

Comment: In Short Circuit 2, he's restored at one point by a defibrillator. I can't recall how he recharges normally, though.

Comment: Johnny 5 ran on a lithium battery, IIRC.

Comment: @phantom42 - great point and very useful info!

Comment: Lithium - argon in the second film;  http://robotics.wikia.com/wiki/Johnny_5

Comment: Maybe when he got hit by lightning, his battery was charged to 400% capacity.

Comment: @MrLister RDJ for Johnny 5 in the reboot confirmed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The S.A.I.N.T. robot (Strategic Artificially Intelligent Nuclear Transport) is powered by a self-contained battery pack stored within the robot's housing.**

In-universe, Johnny 5 is originally powered by a portable battery pack. The pack plugs into a socket located in the robot's lower torso, and is then either replaced by maintenance personnel or recharged directly using a fixed power source. The S.A.I.N.T. robot was designed to carry nuclear ordinance onto a battlefield, and therefore requires a power source that will not require cables, sunlight, or direct current.

Johnny 5 received significant upgrades during his time on the farm with Newton & Stephanie (in-between films). One of these upgrades included replacing the original battery pack with a fixed lithium-argon liquid battery. The new battery can provide enough power for 500 hours of operation. He also has a backup battery which will keep him operative for up to two hours. The composition of this backup battery system is unknown, but at one point after being severely damaged, Johnny 5 is able to recharge it using a [standard external defibrillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defibrillation#Manual_external_defibrillator).

*In the image below, Johnny 5's battery pack - along with a power readout panel - is hidden beneath the blue door on his lower torso:*

[image]

Comment: The script would indicate that they're plugged into a debriefing computer, not a power source; *"Zack and Norman are plugging cables into SAINT number one, hooking it into an array of portable electronic equipment for downloading and post-mission briefing"*

Comment: Good find, @Richard - I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: IIRC it's Ben...jah..min who uses the defibrillator on J5 -- he doesn't use one on himself.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the original battery *was* the backup. It could also have been a bank of identical units where the better one was retained elsewhere, possibly because the others were damaged or used in the first film or some other reason. 2 hours seems very short for a backup system.
We don't know for sure but J5 might have cannibalized parts and the full power packs from the other robots replacing them with his depleted one(s) which would make sense especially if they were removable for charging.
Maybe the spare packs were left at strategic hidden locations "just in case" like supplies? Running out of power for the laser would have sucked.

The defibrillator scene actually makes sense: that electrolyte was probably conductive enough to carry quite a lot of power.